# Cast derived class to base

Tags: c++

What type of cast takes place here (in `B::get()`)?

```
class A {
public:
    A() : a(0) {}
    int a;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    A* get() {
        return this; //is this C-style cast?
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    cout << b.get()->a << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I've seen this kind of code in a famous API. Is it better practice to do `static_cast<A*>(this);`?

Comment: There's no casting at all, only an implicit conversion. A cast is an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a standard derived-to-base pointer conversion. The rules are that a pointer to `D` with some `const`/`volatile` qualifications can be converted to a pointer to `B` with the same qualifiers if `B` is a base class of `D`.

The standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meanings and are separate concepts to things like `static_cast` or C-style casts.

Generally it's best to rely on implicit conversions when you can. Explicit conversions add more code noise and may hide some maintenance mistakes.

Comment: Strictly, "can be converted to a pointer to `B` with the same *or more* qualifiers"

Comment: I suggest specifically answering his question: "No, it is not better practise to use `static_cast` - in fact, it is worse practise.  Always avoid casts if you don't need them."

Comment: @MartinBonner Disagree! Implicit casts are the source of all sorts of wacky bugs. Sometimes I wish C++ didn't even have them at all... Nothing wrong with being explicit.

Comment: @Barry are you referring to standard conversions or user-defined conversion operators or both?

Comment: @Barry can you give an example of a bug caused by implicit cast?

Comment: I'd prefer the phrasing "implicit conversions".  The trouble is that they are still there, but static_cast gives you the opportunity to be explicitly wrong.

Comment: @Barry Also, shouldn't the compile error out if you are about to make an implicit mistake?

Comment: Some kinds of implicit conversions are indeed error-prone, one famous example being the signed-to-unsigned promotion on comparisons. Many tools warn on such conversions, and a cast to alert the reader is a good idea. For a derived-to-base conversion i agree that the cast does more harm than good. If a coding convention requieres a cast here, `static_cast` is the way to go, but i would argue that the convention is broken.

Answer (score 3):

It is implicit conversion to ancestor. Implicit conversions are generally safe and they cannot do stuff `static_cast` cannot do. They actually even more restricted: you can do an unchecked downcast with `static_cast`, but not with implicit conversion.